# Cognitive Services Text Moderation Custom Lists

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Is the listid functionality working for Text Moderation? I created a list and validated that it exists. However when I used the listid in text moderation, the terms from the list are not detected. I also tried using a non-existent listid in the call and no error was returned.
The list is made of simple chars "abc, def, ghi, ijk" and I modified the sample text on the Console page to include these terms. I turned off autocorrect to prevent these 'words' from being modified.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create and use custom lists of terms:

1. Use API to create list that will return a list **Id**
2. Use API to add terms to this list identified by its **Id**
3. Set the list identifier to **listId** query parameter on ProccessText/Screen API

Regards